# Saving a bitmap into a stream

Tags: c#, asp.net, bitmap, stream

I'm trying to resize the uploaded images in ASP.NET by saving the uploaded stream into a bitmap, processing this bitmap and saving the processed bitmap to a new stream that should be saved to an FTP folder. The uploaded stream is successfully saved as a bitmap and processed properly; it's just that there's something wrong with the new processed stream which renders into a corrupted image. Here is the segment of code:

```
        s = FileUpload1.FileContent;
        Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromStream(s);
        Bitmap newBmp = new Bitmap(250, 250, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
        newBmp.SetResolution(72F, 72F);
        Graphics newGraphic = Graphics.FromImage(newBmp);
        newGraphic.Clear(Color.White);
        newGraphic.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
        newGraphic.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
        newGraphic.DrawImage(bitmap, 0, 0, 250, 250);
        newBmp.Save(MapPath("temp.jpg"));
        Stream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        newBmp.Save(memoryStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Comment: I'd appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "saved in FTP"? That's a network protocol, not a file format. And in what way is the result corrupt? Is there an error thrown, or is it a visible issue seen in the result? etc. etc.

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant it should be saved on an FTP folder.

Comment: I'm not sure but i think your problem is with the memoryStream

Comment: No errors are thrown. When I open the new image, it's empty and apparently corrupt.

Comment: Thanks Patrick, but what do you think the problem is?

Comment: When I save the new bitmap to an image in the project, it is perfectly created. However, when it is saved into a stream, something wrong happens.

Comment: I have tried your code here and it seems to work fine, your problem must be on the `FileUpload1.FileContent`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your concern. Well, I think the FileUpload content has no problem since it is successfully saved into a bitmap then processed and saved into a perfect image in this line:
 newBmp.Save(MapPath("temp.jpg"));
Afterwards, that new bitmap should be saved into a new stream that will be uploaded to an FTP folder. May the problem lie in this part? But the FTP file upload in my code works perfectly. What might be the problem then? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @user3030465 where is the FTP file upload in your code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key here is that you are getting an empty image, which is almost always a stream not being read from the beginning.

You need to seek back to the start of the stream after you write your bitmap to it.

```
memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin); //go back to start
```

Otherwise, when you try to save off that stream later, it is reading the stream from the end. When the bitmap writes to the stream, it appends the bytes AND it advances the position.  Here is sample code in MVC that works.

**Index.cshtml**

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("UploadImage", "BitmapConvert", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" })){
    <input type="file" name="uploadFile"/>

    <input type="submit" value="Upload"/>
}
```

**BitmapConvertController.cs**

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MvcSandbox.Controllers
{
    public class BitmapConvertController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult UploadImage(HttpPostedFileBase uploadFile)
        {
            var s = uploadFile.InputStream;

            var bitmap = new Bitmap(s);

            var resizedBitmap = new Bitmap(250, 250, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
            resizedBitmap.SetResolution(72F, 72F);

            using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(resizedBitmap))
            {
                g.Clear(Color.White);
                g.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
                g.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
                g.DrawImage(bitmap, 0, 0, 250, 250);

                resizedBitmap.Save("C:\\Test\\test.jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);

                using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    resizedBitmap.Save(memoryStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);

                    using (var dest = new FileStream("C:\\Test\\stream.jpg", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
                    {
                        memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin); //go back to start
                        memoryStream.CopyTo(dest);
                    }
                }

            }

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks verrrrrrry much.. The problem was as you stated; the memory stream wasn't read from the beginning. When I added the line of memorystream.seek, it worked like a charm. Thanks a million times.